# c# How to create a Method on a Method, or Method Chain

Tags: c#, method-chaining

I have created a simplified SQL Data class, and a class method for returning a ready to use resultset:

```
public SQL_Data(string database) {

    string ConnectionString = GetConnectionString(database);

    cn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);

    try {
        cn.Open();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.Write(e);
        throw;
    }

}

public SqlDataReader DBReader(string query) {

    try {

        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, this.cn)) {
            return cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
        }

    } catch {

        Log.Write("SQL Error with either Connection String:\n" + cn + " \nor Query:\n" + query);
        throw;
    }

}
```

(I catch any errors, log them, and then catch the error higher up the chain.  Also, I did not include the ConnectionString() code for brevity.  It just returns the requested connection string.  That's all.)

This all works just fine, and with a single line of code, I'm ready to `.Read()` rows.

```
SqlDataReader rs = new SQL_Data("MyDatabase").DBReader(@"SELECT * FROM Employees");

while (rs.Read()) {
    // code
}

rs.Close();
```

I want to expand this and add a `.ColumnReader()` method that I want to chain to `.DBReader()` like this:

```
string empID = new SQL_Data("MyDatabase").DBReader(@"SELECT * FROM Employees).ColumnReader("EmpID");
```

I attempted this by adding a `.ColumnReader()` method, but it ends up being a method of `SQL_Data()` class directly, not a member or extension of `.DBReader()`.  I also tried adding the `.ColumnReader()` inside the `.DBReader()` (like a "closure"), but that didn't work either.

Can this be done?

Comment: you can make an [extension method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods) for `SqlDataReader` or convert your `SQL_Data` class into a [fluent interface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface).

Comment: Are you familiar with extension methods?

Comment: @BagusTesa, and Paul.  No, I am not.  But will google that now.  Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: But DBReader returns a SqlDataReader, not a SQL_Data so if you add a ColumnReader method to SQL_Data you cannot call it on the result of DBReader because the result is the wrong type. Have DBReader return a SQL_Data and return`this`. And rename SQL_Data to SqlData; SQL_Data is not to any c# naming convention

Comment: Your method names need some work, I dare say; we don't really name methods with a noun. I'm also not sure what "DBReader" has to do with passing in a string query. Surely something more like this..`new SqlData(...).WithQuery("SELECT ").WithColumn("EmpId")...` makes more sense as "a sentence"

Comment: @CaiusJard, hey, I like that idea!  I think I will change it to reflect that!

Comment: @PaulSinnema, and Bagus!  Hey, the worked great.  I got a bit confused at first thinking I needed to extend my SQL_Data class.  But, then I realised, I need to extend the SqlDataReader class, and it works fine!  Thanks!

Comment: No probs! Just remember that in fluent style writing that chains methods you aren't calling "a method on a method", you're "calling a method and it returns a type, and then you're calling the next method on the returned type" - the ne t method you want to call is present on the type too. Sometimes you might return a different type, and then you call methods on that new one, and then one of the methods you call returns the original type so you're back to calling methods on the first type ..

Answer (score 1):

This ended up working for me:

```
public static class SQLExtentions {

    public static dynamic ColumnReader(this SqlDataReader rs, string colName) {
        return rs[colName];
    }

}
```

I will have to expand on it a bit to add some error checking, and perhaps return more than just the dynamic value - like return an object with the value and it's SQL data type.  But Paul and Bagus' comments got me on the right track.